# Replacing tabs, newspace, whitespace in powershell and calculate SHA1 for that file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to develop a Powershell Script which should:

- Get the content of the file.
- Remove whitespace, newlines, tabs of that file.
- Calculate the SHA1.

Here is my code which I have tried and is not working as it gives me the SHA1 for the file WITH whitespace, newlines and tabs:

```
$File = "C:\MyThirdProject\jpc_flt.txt"
$TargetFile = "C:\MyThirdProject\flttest.txt"
$lines=(Get-Content $File)
$TrimLine = foreach ($line in $lines) { $line.Trim(" `t`n`r") } ##Have tried -->$TrimLine=(Get-Content -LiteralPath $File) | foreach{ $_.Trim(" `t`n`r")} | Set-Content $TargetFile
$TrimLine | Out-File $TargetFile
Get-FileHash -Path $TargetFile -Algorithm SHA1
```

I am open to a different method or any other cmdlets that does this already. Please help!

Comment: You can simply do `$newFile=(Get-Content $File -Raw) -replace '\s+'`

Comment: The `.Trim()` method will remove things from the beginning and end of a string, but not that middle. Is that your intent? If you want to remove all whitespace you can do what Santiago suggested.

Comment: Supposing you want to remove all ***extra*** whitespaces you can do `$newFile=(Get-Content $File -Raw) -replace '\s{2,}'`

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath $TargetFile -NoNewLine -Value (
  (Get-Content -Raw -LiteralPath $File) -replace '\s+'
)

Get-FileHash -LiteralPath $TargetFile -Algorithm SHA1
```

Note the use of `-Raw` (PSv3+) and `-NoNewLine` (PSv5+).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$lines=(Get-Content $File)`

Using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) returns the target file's content as an *array of lines*. (By contrast, using `-Raw` reads the file *as a whole* into a single, multi-line string).

> `$TrimLine | Out-File $TargetFile`

[`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) by default terminate each (stringified) input object with a - platform-appropriate - newline. (`-NoNewLine`, by contrast, places *no* separator between any of the input objects; with a single, multi-line input string, this means that no trailing newline is appended.)